# Sinatra - Accessing request in Rack::ResponseHeaders

Tags: ruby, request, sinatra, response, rack

I want to access request in the Rack::ResponseHeaders. I am using Sinatra in my app.

Below is my code:

```
use Rack::ResponseHeaders do |headers|

  # Manipulation of request variables.
  # Setting request headers.

end
```

The question is that in order to manipulate variables in request, I need to have the request variable first.

Please suggest.

Comment: which variables do you need to manipulate?

Comment: I want to check the request headers. I need to actually set a response header only if request has a certain header in it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is, you need to install the gem `rack-contrib` via rubygems:

```
$ gem install rack-contrib
```

This gem contains contributed rack utilities. Then you need to require this gem in your app:

```
require 'rack/contrib'
```

It may be enough to only require the response headers utility (not tested):

```
require 'rack/contrib/response_headers'
```

Then you can use this utility to tap into the headers, for example:

```
use Rack::ResponseHeaders do |headers|                     # tap into headers
    unless headers['cache-control']                        # if header not set,
        headers['cache-control'] = "public, max-age=1800"  # set it to ...
    end
end
```

Let me know whether this is working for you.